# firefox/cors does not allow application/json contentType in POST requests?

Tags: ajax, firefox, cors

I wanted to send a `json` via POST request (with ajax) to my server, however every attempt was blocked by CORS. Reading about why it's blocked didn't help at all. At some point one of the comments on here claimed, that POST requests with contentType `json` are not allowed (sorry I can't find the relevant post anymore). So I tested something. I wrote the following `php` file:

```
<?php 
header("Access-control-allow-origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(["someVal" => true]);
?>
```

I ran it on port `8081`. Sending a `ajax` POST request with contentType `text/plain` works fine, but `application/json` get's blocked by CORS.

Relevant javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8081/someapi.php",
    contentType: "text/plain", //"application/json",
    method: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {val: "asd"},
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

Why is this the case? Where could I have gotten that info without testing it myself? Is it at all possible to send a `json` via POST request?

Answer (score 2):

POST request with Content-Type: text/plain counts as simple request, as stated by [Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

> Some requests don’t trigger a CORS preflight. Those are called “simple requests” in this article, though the Fetch spec (which defines CORS) doesn’t use that term. A “simple request” is one that meets all the following conditions:
> One of the allowed methods:
>
> - GET
> - HEAD
> - POST
>
> Apart from the headers automatically set by the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, or the other headers defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden header name”), the only headers which are allowed to be manually set are those which the Fetch spec defines as a “CORS-safelisted request-header”, which are:
>
> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below)
>
> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

So if you send a POST request with Content-Type text/plain, you are running a 'simple request'. Meanwhile with application/json, you run a request, which requires a CORS preflight request, and that means the server needs to respond with correct CORS headers to the OPTIONS request sent by the browser.

You can make application/jsonw work as well, but you need to return the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers from your webserver in answer to the OPTIONS request sent by the browser.

Comment: Thanks, what exact header(s) would I have to add to my php file to make this work?

Comment: I would recommend handling CORS on web server level, not at PHP level. Pick the web server of your choice, and follow the guides for it https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Also which headers - that depends on what you want to allow. Access-Control-Allow-Origin lists the websites, which can call that service. Access-Control-Allow-Methods lists the allowed HTTP methods when calling this URL. Access-Control-Allow-Headers lists the headers which are allowed when calling that URL. Plus there are few more headers which are used less frequently (Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Expose-Headers). See the [spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses).